# Identity Specification is making everything troublesome

Tags: sql-server

So, my issue is that I am trying to make something that will easily load in Excel datasheets into a SQL database, but before this I have to try and make the identity specification cooperate with me.

The issue begins when I assign the primary key with identity specification being true, as then I get the error message "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Priskod' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

However when I set that identity specification is false, then I get the error message "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Priskod'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Priskod'. The duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been terminated."

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you maybe provide more details on how you're pushing the data to the table?

Comment: I've removed some information that is not relevant to the question, your urgency should not be key to asking a question, it will only put people off.

Comment: My bet is to leave the IDENTITY on the key field ON, and when importing the Excel sheet do not map the key field

Comment: At the moment I am trying to actually make it enter the data as the first row being ID 1, then the next being ID 2, etc. When Identity is turned on, it cannot create the ID at all since it is saying that the Identity on the second column, which is named Priskod, is set to off, but when I turn the identity insert on at it, it is saying even then that Identity is not turned on. When I turn off Identity on ID, then it is giving the second error message.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you have an Excel spreadsheet that holds data that you want to import into a SQL Server table.

The issue is that you are trying to load it directly in to the source table and to enable this, you are disabling the `IDENTITY` column. This should ring alarm bells really, as SQL is right when it prevents you from inserting duplicate keys.

There are 2 options here:

1. The key values in Excel are true identity values that are unique, so you will only `INSERT` records they don't exist in the target table. This would probably be best achieved by importing to a staging/temp table first and the inserting where the `ID` doesn't exist. You may also want to perform an `UPDATE` on rows where the `ID` does exist.
2. The key values in Excel are NOT true identity values.

Either way, I think you should add a new column to your target table like: `ExternalId`, which can be duplicated if required or checked against to prevent duplicates. With both approaches, you should leave the `IDENTITY` insert as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Got the system to work now.
I had to enter the information straight into the database instead of actually trying to upload the information into the database itself. So thanks everyone for your help and support. You are all super.